# what is a user stall?

Tags: database, terminology

I am reading a white paper on [volt db](http://odbms.org/download/VoltDBTechnicalOverview.pdf). The white paper says volt does not experience "user stalls." What does this mean? How does a traditional RDBMS experience user stalls?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they mean the transaction doesn't require user interaction , I am reading a paper [The end of an Architectural Era: (It’s Time for a Complete Rewrite)](http://nms.csail.mit.edu/~stavros/pubs/hstore.pdf) and they said

> In addition, most OLTP environments we are familiar with do not have “user stalls”. For example, when an Amazon user clicks “buy it”, he activates an OLTP transaction which will only report back to the user when it finishes.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

A user stall is created when the database transaction waits on a user action.  So the transactions is started, locks some records, and then pauses while information is presented to the user, and waits for an action.  This is a poor design, and I'm not sure why Volt makes a point of mentioning it.  The usual method is to maintain a timestamp or counter in each record that is update each time the record is updated.  This info is read before the stall, and any locks are dropped before the information is presented to the user.  After the user action, the resulting (new) transaction will check the timestamp or counter, and if it has changed, can decide whether or not to proceed.